# How to find all elements of a web page (only 25 load instead of all of them)

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm getting all the quotes from https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/oscar_wilde and adding the text of each element into a List of type String and everything works as it should. My issue is that it is not grabbing every single element from the website. It only ends up grabbing 25 each time. I tested this by loading the quotes and printing out the size of the list, which results in 25. Is there a way to load every single element using jsoup so that I can grab all of the quotes?

This is the relevant class. As I said, everything works as it should. The only problem is grabbing all quotes instead of only 25. Note: Ignore the fact that I start the index at 21, the same thing happens when I start it at 0.

```java
package com.galanjulio.pequitas.quotes;

import com.galanjulio.pequitas.Pequitas;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QuoteHandler {

    private Document document;

    private List<String> quotes;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int index;

    public QuoteHandler() {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/oscar_wilde").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        index = 21;
        quotes = new ArrayList<>();

        loadQuotes();
    }

    public String getNextQuote() {
        index++;

        if (index >= quotes.size()) {
            index = 0;
        }

        Pequitas.getInstance().saveSettings();

        return quotes.get(index);
    }

    private void loadQuotes() {
        List<Element> elements = document.getElementsByClass("b-qt");

        for (Element element : elements) {
            quotes.add(element.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at the page: I see 26 elements with that class name. There are not more than these. The _next_ quotes are on another page. This site uses _paging_!

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve that page using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), you will see that only 26 quotes are actually included in the page. The remaining quotes that you see when you use a browser are loaded dynamically using Javascript.

```
$ curl -s https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/oscar_wilde | grep b-qt | wc -l
26
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. What do you think would be the best approach to achieve my goal then?

Comment: Probably just use a service with a proper API instead of trying to extract the data from a web page. Googling "quotes API" or "quotes REST API" should give you some starting points.